# Assign class labels using nearest neighbor classifier in R

Tags: r, classification

I'm lost on where to begin on this one. My assignment, using the IRIS dataset built into R is:

Write a piece of R code that assigns a single class label to each of the OBSERVATIONS (four-dimensional), using the nearest-neighbor classifier (NN)[1]. Use Part A as the reference database (observations and class labels), and Part B as testing set. Assume you do not know the class labels of Part B, for each observation from Part B find the nearest observation from Part A and assign its class label to the observation from Part A).

Calculate and return per-class accuracy (number of correctly classified observations per class divided by the total  number of observations).

The code I've written for the first part is quite simple:

```
newData = iris

evenRows.A <- newData[seq(2, nrow(newData), 2),]  #SELECT EVEN ROWS

oddRows.B <- newData[seq(1, nrow(newData), 2),]   #SELECT ODD ROWS. This is the testing set
```

Any help on the class labels would already be much appreciated.

EDIT: formatted R code

Answer (score 1):

```
    newData = iris
    evenRows.A <- newData[seq(2, nrow(newData), 2),]  #SELECT EVEN ROWS
    oddRows.B <- newData[seq(1, nrow(newData), 2),]   #SELECT ODD ROWS. This is the testing set

normalize <- function(x){return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))}       #Define a function to normalize the data
    evenRows.train<- as.data.frame(normalize(evenRows.A[,c(1,2,3,4)]))  #Apply normalization to part A, the reference data
    oddRows.test<- as.data.frame(normalize(oddRows.B[,c(1,2,3,4)]))    #Apply normalization to part B, the test data
    evenRows.train.target<-evenRows.A[,5]

    require(class)  #load required classes for nearest neighbor modelling
    sqrt(150)
    #rule of thumb: pick k= sqrt(observations), rounded to nearest odd integer. In this case, 12.247 --> k = 13

    model1<-knn(train=evenRows.train, test=oddRows.test, cl=evenRows.train.target, k=13)
    model1

    #Display confusion matrix of results, to quantify correct versus incorrect classification

    table(oddRows.test.target, model1)
```

I have an attempt at applying k nearest neighbors classification, and displayed the results as a confusion matrix at the end. Can you all tell me whether this is a sensible approach to the question I posted?